# ignore does not work in build flow plugin in jenkins

Tags: plugins, jenkins, dsl

```
build( "UPGRADE_LOGGED_94" )
parallel (
    // job 1, 2 and 3 will be scheduled in parallel.
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_TICKET") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_SALESLEAD") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_SEARCH") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_HOME") },

    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_BUSINESS") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_ANNOUNCEMENT") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_PROJECT") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_CHANGEREQ") },

    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_CALENDAR") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_CUSTOMER") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_DEVELOPREQ") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_NAVIGATION") },

    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_NOTIFICATION") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_RECURWORKFLOW") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_SLLIFE") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_REPORTING") },

    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_TASK") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_TRIAGE") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_USER") },
    { build("LOGGED_SMOKE_WORKFLOW") },



)


ignore(ABORTED ) {
  parallel (
    {build( "LOGGED_SMOKE_TICKETLIFE" )},
    {build( "LOGGED_SMOKE_WORKFLOWLIFE" )}
    )

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear :( Please indents all your code and explains what is failing.

Comment: It seems the job in "IGNORE" sentence does not execute. Now I solved the issue since IGNORE should put it into upstream job.

Answer (score 0):

Use IGNORE sentence in upstream job. For example there is job 1 and job 2

```
build("job1")
build("job2")
```

if you want job2 will be executed even if job1 fails, you should write

```
IGNORE(FAILURE){
build("job1")
}
build("job2")
```